# do a count of x of y records uploaded - php

Tags: php

I have a upload script, working fine.  But I cannot seem to get an output to the user saying, record 1 of 10 files uploaded.

I could do something like
record 1 of 10 files uploaded
record 2 of 10 files uploaded
record 3 of 10 files uploaded
record 4 of 10 files uploaded
...

..
record 10 of 10 files uploaded

which is easy.

How do I increment the number like uploading x 0f 10 where x increments only using php.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Are you talking about web application? Is "output" a web page shown to user? Could you please clarify, since now it's not easy to understand the question.

Comment: @kel Yes, its a web app, and also I mentioned PHP

Comment: Amazing None know the solution?

Comment: Don't think you can using only PHP.  You will have to have some asynchronous javascript that records the file uploads and prints results to the screen.

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery or just regular javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I increment the number like
>   uploading x 0f 10 where x increments
>   only using php.

Since PHP script is a server-side program, which only generates response on client request, the answer is, there's no way to do it ONLY with PHP.

You need to use some client-side scripting (javascript), which will make periodic requests to your server and obtain current status. Good idea is to use some AJAX framework (jQuery). Also, I suppose, there are already some solutions, since the problem seems rather common.

I'm not a jQuery specialist, but simple search resulted in the following article: http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/